# blogger json - how to fetch category/label?

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

Based on the following pattern, how to create a variable to fetch the labels from json?

```
var postLink = function(entry) {
    for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++) {
        if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
            var postURL = entry.link[j].href;
            return postURL;
            break;
        }
    }
};

var postTitle = function(entry) {
    var postTitle = entry.title.$t;
    return postTitle;
};

function Full(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var item1 = '<h3><a href="' + postLink(entry) + '">' + postTitle(entry) + '</a></h3>';
        document.write(item1);
    }
}
```

this code to print the results:

```
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/LABEL?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=Full&amp;max-results=2"></script>
```

the result is for post title and link only... I just wanted to add the variable code for label as well...

I wanted the code inside:

```
var postLabel = function(entry) {
        //some code here
};
```

... and inside `var item1` I will add this : `+ postLabel(entry) +`

I need to follow the pattern of postLink and postTitle but it's beyond my ability... thanks for your help!

Comment: you... forgot to include the json and how you're calling `Full`. Is this jsonp?

Comment: I did ask for clarification. You still haven't provided any.

Comment: I added some more details :)

Comment: I read through this but I just can't implement it... http://www.danpros.com/2013/08/blogger-json-feed-api

Comment: i still don't see any json in your question. How are we supposed to help you navigate through a json string we can't see?

Comment: sorry I just don't know the terms yet.... but I solved my problem already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error, I found a solution by basing it with other similar codes! I only knew css and I'm starting to like js :)

```
var postLabel = function(entry) {
   var postLabel =  entry.category[0].term;
    return postLabel;
};
```